# Selenium - WebDriver & Chrome Driver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have newly setup the selenium in my pc.
I have installed 9.0.4 Java and installed the eclipse oxygen. I have configured the environment variables and downloaded chrome driver is placed in my folders.
I have downloaded the selenium jar files configured those as well.

But, when I type the webdriver in the selenium code, I am getting the error prompt at left side as per the attached snap in this message.

Can some one please look into this and suggest to proceed further ?

Thanks,
Venkat

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have you put your jar file outside the project , if you have done , you have to set Deployment Assembly along with build path. Just right click on project , go to properties and set this.

Comment: Thanks for your quick suggestion. can you please tell where the Deployment Assembly. Please find the attached Jar files that I have setup. Please refer the second snap above.

Comment: as per your screenshot, i think selenium jar file is missing
Pls go through with this link
https://www.journaldev.com/25837/download-selenium-jars-configure-eclipse#selenium-jars-download

Comment: Thanks. if I go to this link.. 
 https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/, I have downloaded java related jar files.        
 I would see only those listed jars.

Comment: in the available jar files, I don't see jar file name with selenium !! Can you please help me to get that and add the same ??

Comment: Use link, which I have mentioned in my comments

Comment: hi sachin, i have used the same link only. Except the above mentioned jar files, I am not finding any jar file. can you please help me to proceed ?

Comment: I found one selenium jar which did not come along with the .zip file. Please observe the file whether it is correct or not as per the above third snap ?

Answer (score 1):

1)selenium jar is missing in library folder so You can do one thing... Create a folder into your project and and copy selenium jar, and build path the project and select selenium jar, you will get entry into library folder.

2)Refresh the project or restart your eclipse

Comment: 1. From where I need to copy the selenium jar file ? Is it a different new file ? What is the folder that I need to create in the project and what is it for ? Can you please more elaborate, Ghanshyam ?

Comment: Download the selenium jar file and make a folder(Whatever name you can provide) in your project. and put that downloaded jar into that folder and, right click project and goto build path browse library from that folder. refresh your project and restart eclipse you will get an entry into your library folder.

Comment: Thank you. I am not getting the selenium jar file from .. selenium.dev/downloads.                 client-combined-3.141.59, client-combined-3.141.59-sources, byte-buddy-1.8.15, commons-exec-1.3, guava-25.0-jre, okhttp-3.11.0, okio-1.14.0 - except these files.

Comment: Ghanshyam,  Please refer the above THIRD snap that I have shared, please observe the selenium jar whether it is correct or not. As per your suggestion, I have created folder and added. Now the error mark for the webdriver is not there. But it has some warning indicator if you observe !!

Comment: Yes, it's fine, and good , it will work, and worning is because you just created object of driver not using it,,, when you will use warning will washout.

Comment: Excellent.. Ghanshyam. Thank You. But, I have observed that I need to type import org.* and and other packages. It did not come automatically.  & my current browser version is 81 and downloaded webdriver also 81. It says that "Chrome version must be between 71 and 75". Can you please clarify the above ?

Comment: Bro, do one thing , uninstall your browser and install new browser of version 71 or less than version 75.

Comment: Thank You, I will do that.  In the code, I have observed that I need to type import org.* and and other packages. It did not come automatically. I remember, it comes automatically. right !!